# PHP+MySQL: searching using wildcards

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

So, I have the following rows in the DB:

1 | /users/

2 | /users/admin/

3 | /users/admin/*

4 | /users/admin/mike/

5 | /users/admin/steve/docs/

The input URL is **/users/admin/steve/**, and the goal is to find the URL match from the DB.

I want to return #3 as the correct row, since the wildcard "*" specifies that anything can go in place of the asterisk. What would be the most efficient method for doing this?

**Here's my initial thoughts, but I'm sure they could be improved upon:**

1. Make a query to see if there's an exact URL match
2. If no matches, then retrieve all rows with "*" as the last character, in reverse order (so the more specific URLs take precedence)
3. For each row, if it (minus the "*") matches the input URL, then return it
4. If nothing is found, then we're SOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable AS m
WHERE <input-url> = m.urlpattern
 OR <input-url> REGEXP REPLACE(m.urlpattern, '*', '.*');
```

The REPLACE() is to change the globbing-style wildcard into an equivalent regular-expression wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, something like this should work:

SELECT COALESCE(

> (SELECT whatever FROM your query to see if there is an exact url),
>     (SELECT next approximation),
>     'SOL'

)